# Problems with dependencies while trying to install libmupen64plus

Tags: software-center, dpkg, dependencies, deb

Trying to install libmupen64plus2:i386 on a 64-bit Linux 16.04. It's a .deb file and i opened it using the Ubuntu Software Center. During the install I was returned with this error notification.

```
Setting up libftgl2:i386 (2.1.3~rc5-4+nmu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmupen64plus2:i386.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 250250 files and directories currently     installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libmupen64plus2_1.99.4-4_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libmupen64plus2:i386 (1.99.4-4) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of     libmupen64plus2:i386:
 libmupen64plus2:i386 depends on ttf-dejavu-core.

dpkg: error processing package libmupen64plus2:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libmupen64plus2:i386
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im afraid you have to install the `depends` package, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to go to a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-dejavu-core
```

Followed by installation of `libmupen64plus2:i386` that you mentioned.